# Change colour of geom_point for maximum y value

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, geom-point

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Salary        Year
15             1990
16             1991
15             1992
20             1993
17             1994
19             1995
```

Which I plot using the ggplot.

```
Dataframe %>%
   ggplot(aes(Year, Salary)) +
   geom_line() + 
   geom_point()
```

Which results in this graph:

[image]

**What I want to do is to mark the point who is at salary 20 in a black circle (like it is right now) while  the rest of the points are white circles with a black ring.** How do I do that?

Comment: Everything works great except for the white circles which I want to have a black ring around so it's easier to notice. @akrun

Comment: That's wonderful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a binary variable (a condition) as `fill` aesthetics.
And `shape = 21`. From the help page `?points`:

> pch = 21: filled circle

```r
x<-'Salary        Year
15             1990
16             1991
15             1992
20             1993
17             1994
19             1995'
Dataframe <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Dataframe, aes(Year, Salary, fill = Salary == 20, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(`FALSE` = 'white', `TRUE` = 'black'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

An option is to add a second call with `geom_point` on the subset of dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Dataframe  %>%
   ggplot(aes(Year, Salary)) +
     geom_line() + 
     geom_point() +
     geom_point(data = Dataframe %>% filter(Salary != max(Salary)),
      pch = 21, fill = "white", colour = "black")
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
Dataframe <- structure(list(Salary = c(15L, 16L, 15L, 20L, 17L,
 19L), Year = 1990:1995), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```